# batch script: why if and else batch run after if condition failed?

Tags: batch

[image: 1]

---

```bat
@echo off
set tempfile=C:\Users\*\Desktop\test case\temp\tempfile.txt
if not exist %tempfile% (
    echo if branch
    echo %TIME%
    type nul>%tempfile%
) else ( 
    echo else branch
    echo %TIME%
    echo file has already exist!
    echo =============%DATE% %TIME%==========>>%tempfile%
    echo 123>>%tempfile%
)
```

Comment: Your code is quite unreable because you just copy/pasted the script without using the Code-formatting options in the markup editor. We can try to guess what the original code looked like, but without the exact layout of the code it is impossible to tell if you made a subtle syntax error. Please read the FAQ and EDIT your post to fix the formatting problems.

Comment: Just as a guess. The asterix (*) character in the TEMPFILE variable probably screws up the IF. You can't use IF with wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to have this habit of using :

- The `%userprofile%` environment variable instead of `c:\users\%username%\*\...`
- Further Reading [How to open your user profile folder in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000109.htm)
- Adding double quotes to this variable `"%tempfile%"` since your file contains spaces.

So your code can be written like this :

---

```bat
@echo off
set tempfile=%userprofile%\Desktop\test case\temp\tempfile.txt

if not exist "%tempfile%" (
    echo if branch
    echo %TIME%
    type nul>"%tempfile%"
) else ( 
    echo else branch
    echo %TIME%
    echo file has already exist!
    echo =============%DATE% %TIME%==========>>"%tempfile%"
    echo 123>>"%tempfile%"
)
pause>nul
```